# How to trigger the event of cell when we move mouse from that cell in slickgrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I would like to trigger the event to save the row data into DB when user enter text in the texteditor cell of slick grid and moves the mouse out of that cell.I have subscribed the CellChanged event , it is working but I would like to save the row data when user moves the mouse and click out of the grid. I have tried of using the all the slickgrid events given iin the API doc.